# Node-RED keeps crashing whenever I try to connect to Azure IoT Hub

Tags: node-red, azure-iot-hub

[image: The screen shot shows the error I get whenever I try to inject data into the Azure IoT Hub node]

Below you'll find the flow I used from a YouTube video tutorial.  I made sure to copy & past the "deviceID" and "SAK" from my azure portal perfectly just like the YouTube video suggested and yet I keep getting connection errors.  I've also tried other flows and tutorials and yet I keep getting the same errors. Can somebody please help ?

```
[{"id":"191eb7ca.b71a8","type":"azureiothub","z":"2ac65269.04174e","name":"Azure IoT Hub","protocol":"mqtt","x":458,"y":349,"wires":[["39c7854c.56d18a"]]},{"id":"aa561f4a.a44358","type":"function","z":"2ac65269.04174e","name":"Function","func":"msg1 = '{\"deviceID\": \"Arduino001\", '\nmsg1 = msg1 + '\"SAK\": \"Yub6LJ9vjuPaJ4zWXCPEYr8+eRByyCUwB3h8VefIlEE=\", '  \nmsg1 = msg1 + '\"Protocol\": \"mqtt\", '\nmsg1 = msg1 + '\"Data\": { \"' + msg.topic + '\": \"' + msg.payload + '\"}}'\n\nnewMsg = { payload: msg1 };\nreturn newMsg;\n","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":322,"y":511,"wires":[["191eb7ca.b71a8","39c7854c.56d18a"]]},{"id":"48115883.03fae8","type":"inject","z":"2ac65269.04174e","name":"Speed","topic":"speed","payload":"345","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":139,"y":476,"wires":[["aa561f4a.a44358"]]},{"id":"39c7854c.56d18a","type":"debug","z":"2ac65269.04174e","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"payload","x":626.3400268554688,"y":439.47998046875,"wires":[]},{"id":"31ae88af.f84fa","type":"inject","z":"2ac65269.04174e","name":"Temperature","topic":"temperature","payload":"87","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":157,"y":512,"wires":[["aa561f4a.a44358"]]},{"id":"fc5e350.8f97e48","type":"inject","z":"2ac65269.04174e","name":"Pressure","topic":"pressure","payload":"2342","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":147,"y":548,"wires":[["aa561f4a.a44358"]]},{"id":"f3fce0b1.76ed6","type":"inject","z":"2ac65269.04174e","name":"Send Multiple Values","topic":"","payload":"{\"deviceID\": \"Arduino001\", \"SAK\": \"Yub6LJ9vjuPaJ4zWXCPEYr8+eRByyCUwB3h8VefIlEE=\", \"Protocol\": \"mqtt\", \"Data\": { \"AvgFlowRate\" : 500, \"FlowRate\" : 700, \"AvgStaticPressure\" : 525, \"StaticPressure\" : 518, \"AvgCasingPressure\" : 776, \"CasingPressure\" : 805, \"AvgTubingPressure\" : 609, \"TubingPressure\" : 588}}","payloadType":"json","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":178,"y":337,"wires":[["191eb7ca.b71a8"]]},{"id":"15aa66ba.d05be9","type":"inject","z":"2ac65269.04174e","name":"Send one value","topic":"","payload":"{\"deviceID\": \"Arduino001\", \"SAK\": \"Yub6LJ9vjuPaJ4zWXCPEYr8+eRByyCUwB3h8VefIlEE=\", \"Protocol\": \"mqtt\", \"Data\": { \"Speed\" : \"25\"}}","payloadType":"json","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":155.90994262695312,"y":299.0900192260742,"wires":[["191eb7ca.b71a8"]]},{"id":"24956e6.952af12","type":"inject","z":"2ac65269.04174e","name":"Send one value","topic":"","payload":"{\"deviceID\": \"Device1\", \"SAK\": \"AuCI9KBBg0WY9+KbEZLiDsN/cn8JTf6se5BJYcJhCws=\", \"Protocol\": \"mqtt\", \"Data\": { \"Speed\" : \"25\"}}","payloadType":"json","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":161,"y":231,"wires":[["191eb7ca.b71a8"]]}]
```

Comment: Please do not post images of text, they are very hard to read, and impossible for people that use screen readers (you also can't search for them). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70260134/edit) the question to post the actual text and then format it with the toolbar. Likewise with the flow.

Answer (score 0):

The logs show that the `deviceID` and `SAK` are null which either means you didn't add them to the nodes config or the node has a bug that is not using them.

Also the node needs better error handling so it doesn't crash if the connection fails. You will need to raise this directly with the author of the node, most likely on github here: https://github.com/lcarli/NodeRedIoTHub/issues

But it is worth noting that the node hasn't been updated in the last 4 years.